# Scrape table, exclude rows with certain class, and assign attribute value to variable per row

Tags: r, xpath

I have a page with the following html.

```
<table id="batting_gamelogs">
 <tbody>
  <tr class id="batting_gamelogs.153">
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td>
    <span id="PHA192504150-simmoal01">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class id="batting_gamelogs.154">
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td>
    <span id="PHA192504160-simmoal01">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class ="thead">
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using the following code to scrape the table.

```
data = NULL
batlist = NULL

battingURLs <- paste("http://www.baseball- reference.com",yplist[,c("hrefs")],sep="")

for(thisbattingURL in battingURLs){

batting <- htmlParse(thisbattingURL)

fstampid <- regexpr("&", thisbattingURL, fixed=TRUE)-1
fstampyr <- regexpr("year=", thisbattingURL, fixed=TRUE)+5
id <- substr(thisbattingURL, 53, fstampid)
year <- substr(thisbattingURL, fstampyr, 75)

if (length(xpathSApply(batting, '//*[@id = "batting_gamelogs"]', xmlValue))==0) next

tableNode <- xpathSApply(batting, '//*[@id="batting_gamelogs"]')[[1]]
data <- readHTMLTable(tableNode, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data # select the first table
total <- cbind(id,year,data)

batlist <- bind_rows(batlist, total)

}
```

I would like to leave out any row with the class "thead".  I don't know if it would be easier to scrape the whole table and then delete the unwanted rows later or just not grab them in the first place.  I would also like to assign the span id to a variable called gameid for each row in the table I scrape.

The code I am using to scrape the table grabs the whole table at once I think, but I'm not sure as I'm new to R.  I've tried searching here, but I can't make heads or tails of anything I have found.

The code I'm using to set the gameid works when I test with one URL and choose a specific tr class id, but doesn't when I use contains.  I'm not sure if it's because I'm running in a loop and scraping the whole table at once or not.

```
gameid <- xpathSApply(batting, '//*[@id="batting_gamelogs.153"]/td[10]/span/@id')
```

returns this "PHA192504150-simmoal01" and it will be different/unique for every row of the table.

When I run in the loop I'm trying the following code

```
gameid <- xpathSApply(batting, '//*[contains(., "batting_gamelogs."]/td[10]/span/@id')
```

From there I'll just cbind gameid with the other variables at the end of the code.  I don't have it in there now because it's not working.

Thanks for any help, it is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What happen if you close `contains()` function properly, will your codes then work? `//*[contains(., "batting_gamelogs.")]/td[10]/span/@id`

Comment: @har07 thanks for your help again!  It returns a NULL value.

the following code returns "SDN199004230-quiseda01"
`gameid <- xpathSApply(batting, '//*[@id="batting_gamelogs.674"]/td[10]/span/@id')`

This code returns NULL

`gameid <- xpathSApply(batting, '//*[contains(., "batting_gamelogs.")]/td[10]/span/@id')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pull the gameid from the table by correcting the code like @har07 suggested and switching the . to @id in the contains.

```
gameid <- xpathSApply(batting, '//*[contains(., "batting_gamelogs.")]/td[10]/span/@id')
```

now looks like

```
gameid <- xpathSApply(batting, '//*[contains(@id, "batting_gamelogs.")]/td[10]/span/@id')
```

I was also able to exclude rows by subsetting the current data.frame.  I added this line of code to create a new data.frame without useless headers and misc rows.

```
newdata <- subset(data, Rk!="April" & Rk!="May" & Rk!="June" & Rk!="July" & Rk!="August" & Rk!="September" & Rk!="October" & Rk!="November" & Opp!="<NA>")
```